# mix shader fac is adding buff to white color on object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shader-nodes, filmic-blender

I created single material to control all object colors based on random. If you can see the product name thy lathe shampoo in black and in white is of different thickness. if someone can help with fixing/making that even in blender. any help would be appreciated.

The render:

[image]

The material:

[image]

Blender cycles 3.6

Comment: The rendered color is the light-response of the surface with that color, (including the bounce from the other packages) not the color of the 'ink'. Are you sure you want to break the physics to achieve pure whites and blacks? One option could be to pull tricks as in a real-life packshot, and put concealed white cards, or equivalent, on the backs of the packs.

Comment: is there a better way to do it? can you please point out where I broke physics?

Comment: I mean, if you want the logos to be pure white, _that_ would break physics. At the moment, the approximation is fairly accurate. (e.g. the logo on the red package is slightly yellow, lit partly by the bounce from the yellow package). EEVEE would be less accurate, in these respects, and may be better for you.